# gnome-session-properties won't work when the monitor is not connect

Tags: scripts

I use Ubuntu 20.04. And I set up a script with startup of Ubuntu in startup application preferences(gnome-session-properties). I need to run the script(.sh) without the monitor connected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvOM5.png)

However, when the monitor connects to the computer with HDMI, the script would work with startup. While the monitor is not connected, the script is not working until the HDMI re-connect the computer.

Why this happens? Is there anything prevent the script working? Or does the startup script only work when there is a "monitor"?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: When I boot Ubuntu without the monitor connected, I type "Ctrl_alt+T" to open the terminal several times, then I connect the monitor, the desktop is very clear without any terminals open! I was sure the keyboard is connected well, because I tested to open the terminals after the monitor connected.

Comment: Any new info about the question needs to be added to the question with edit not made as a comment.